# Trackpad and keyboard erratic behaviour on Thinkpad Yoga (15.10)

Tags: keyboard, 15.10, mouse, touchpad, thinkpad

I'm trying to troubleshoot some problems that have been plaguing my Thinkpad Yoga, running 15.10. First up, the trackpad stops working for seconds at a time. This alone makes it almost unusable. But I can persevere using the touchscreen if needed. However, when the trackpad is in a 'stopped working' state, the keyboard starts behaving very strangely. Sometimes a key will get 'stuck' for a second or so even though I've only touched it once. Other times, keys will arrive in the application out of order compared to what I typed. Sometimes there will be a lag between pressing a key and it appearing (often combined with it then appearing repeatedly). The problems don't occur when I'm using an external keyboard/mouse. And sometimes it works fine for ages, and I'm struggling to find any patterns why. Syslog shows the following when the mouse problem occurs:

```
Mar 23 20:03:51 vikyoga kernel: [50808.978899] psmouse serio1: synaptics: Unable to query device.
Mar 23 20:03:51 vikyoga kernel: [50809.272629] psmouse serio1: Failed to enable mouse on isa0060/serio1
Mar 23 20:03:56 vikyoga kernel: [50813.585592] psmouse serio1: synaptics: queried max coordinates: x [..5708], y [..4698]
Mar 23 20:03:56 vikyoga kernel: [50813.635092] psmouse serio1: synaptics: queried min coordinates: x [1232..], y [1156..]
Mar 23 20:03:56 vikyoga kernel: [50813.635098] psmouse serio1: synaptics: quirked min/max coordinates: x [1232..5710], y [1156..4696]
Mar 23 20:03:56 vikyoga kernel: [50813.717897] psmouse serio1: synaptics: Touchpad model: 1, fw: 8.1, id: 0x1e2b1, caps: 0xd002a3/0x940300/0x12f800/0x0, board id: 2911, fw id: 2560
Mar 23 20:03:56 vikyoga kernel: [50813.717910] psmouse serio1: synaptics: serio: Synaptics pass-through port at isa0060/serio1/input0
Mar 23 20:03:56 vikyoga kernel: [50813.770900] input: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input97
Mar 23 20:04:02 vikyoga kernel: [50819.665042] psmouse serio11: trackpoint: IBM TrackPoint firmware: 0x0e, buttons: 3/3
Mar 23 20:04:02 vikyoga kernel: [50819.956214] input: TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/serio11/input/input98
Mar 23 20:04:08 vikyoga kernel: [50826.265209] psmouse serio1: TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost synchronization, throwing 3 bytes away.
Mar 23 20:04:09 vikyoga kernel: [50826.776467] psmouse serio1: resync failed, issuing reconnect request
Mar 23 20:04:10 vikyoga kernel: [50827.636047] psmouse serio1: synaptics: queried max coordinates: x [..5708], y [..4698]
Mar 23 20:04:10 vikyoga kernel: [50827.686367] psmouse serio1: synaptics: queried min coordinates: x [1232..], y [1156..]
Mar 23 20:04:10 vikyoga kernel: [50827.686373] psmouse serio1: synaptics: quirked min/max coordinates: x [1232..5710], y [1156..4696]
Mar 23 20:04:16 vikyoga kernel: [50833.581811] psmouse serio1: TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost synchronization, throwing 2 bytes away.
Mar 23 20:04:16 vikyoga kernel: [50834.095495] psmouse serio1: resync failed, issuing reconnect request
Mar 23 20:04:17 vikyoga kernel: [50834.954826] psmouse serio1: synaptics: queried max coordinates: x [..5708], y [..4698]
Mar 23 20:04:17 vikyoga kernel: [50835.002697] psmouse serio1: synaptics: queried min coordinates: x [1232..], y [1156..]
Mar 23 20:04:17 vikyoga kernel: [50835.002703] psmouse serio1: synaptics: quirked min/max coordinates: x [1232..5710], y [1156..4696]
Mar 23 20:04:18 vikyoga kernel: [50836.126420] psmouse serio1: synaptics: failed to switch guest protocol
Mar 23 20:04:18 vikyoga kernel: [50836.372889] psmouse serio11: Failed to enable mouse on synaptics-pt/serio0
Mar 23 20:04:19 vikyoga kernel: [50836.433490] psmouse serio1: TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost sync at byte 1
Mar 23 20:04:19 vikyoga kernel: [50836.434537] psmouse serio1: TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost sync at byte 1
Mar 23 20:04:19 vikyoga kernel: [50836.435719] psmouse serio1: TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost sync at byte 1
Mar 23 20:04:19 vikyoga kernel: [50836.442576] psmouse serio1: TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost sync at byte 1
Mar 23 20:04:19 vikyoga kernel: [50836.443716] psmouse serio1: TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost sync at byte 1
Mar 23 20:04:19 vikyoga kernel: [50836.443718] psmouse serio1: issuing reconnect request
Mar 23 20:04:20 vikyoga kernel: [50837.794841] psmouse serio1: synaptics: queried max coordinates: x [..5708], y [..4698]
Mar 23 20:04:20 vikyoga kernel: [50837.842572] psmouse serio1: synaptics: queried min coordinates: x [1232..], y [1156..]
Mar 23 20:04:20 vikyoga kernel: [50837.842578] psmouse serio1: synaptics: quirked min/max coordinates: x [1232..5710], y [1156..4696]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please don't use backticks for long blocks of text. Instead, highlight the block and press the `{}` button.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to have been a connection issue - I took the machine apart, re-seated the keyboard and trackpad connectors, and haven't had any problems since. Hopefully will stay that way.

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling your accelerometer in your BIOS and see if the problem persists. I've found that these messages come up when I flip my computer upside down.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but alas it didn't do anything