# Laptop randomly blocks keyboard, trackpad and wifi

Tags: keyboard, touchpad, lenovo

I have a Lenovo Yoga 2 with Xubuntu 16.04.

Sometimes, out of nowhere my keyboard stops working, so does my trackpad and the computer goes on some kind of airplane mode (wifi and bluetooth on). However, the touchscreen still works at all time.

I've seen [Trackpad and keyboard erratic behaviour on Thinkpad Yoga (15.10)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/749280/trackpad-and-keyboard-erratic-behaviour-on-thinkpad-yoga-15-10) but I can't run syslog since I can barely use my computer.

I'd like to point out that this case is different from the one mentioned above since I can't use the keyboard or mouse again until I reboot, plus the OP in that question never mentioned losing wifi or bluetooth connections.

One of the answers said to disable the accelerometer in the BIOS but I couldn't find any setting regarding it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't know why you mention the "accelerometer"?!? That half-baked answer has a comment stating it did nothing. Below that answer there's this https://askubuntu.com/a/761588/692175 which is from the OP.

Comment: @MichaelBay I'd like to avoid opening the computer if possible. Plus I've noticed that sometimes the blocking happens when I move the laptop

Comment: There are professionals for that. You don't have to do it yourself and you shouldn't if you aren't comfortable with the idea. That said, the *sometimes the blocking happens when I move the laptop* pretty much confirms this is an hardware issue and as such off topic here.

Comment: @MichaelBay I suspect this is not related to the laptop's accelerometer, but [accelerometers are real things that many laptops have](https://superuser.com/questions/149407/why-does-my-hp-pavilion-notebook-have-an-accelerometer). I suspect that the answer you refer to as "half-baked" is actually a correct answer... for somebody. Definitely not for that question's asker, and probably not for most people, since a bug or other driver problem would presumably have to be involved for accelerometry/gravimetry to affect human input devices. I agree that a loose connection is a more likely explanation.

Comment: Before you dismiss the linked question, did you try any of its answers? Just because *some* conditions and symptoms are different that doesn't mean the *cause* is different.